# Вывод данных из промежуточной М2М модели

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, django-orm

Есть таблица `Cart` с подключением М2М к `Product`. Из созданной промежуточной модели нужно сделать выборку данных и передать их в HTML для вывода в корзине пользователя.

Не понимаю как именно нужно сделать выборку, учитывая, что Django жалуется, что М2М `not iterable` и не имеет атрибута `filter`

````
#html
<div id="cart">
    {% for i in cart %}
    <ul><li>{{i.product}}</li></ul>
    <h1>{{i}}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

#views
def get_cart(request):
    cart = Product.cart_set
    # cart = Cart.product.all(username=request.user)
    return render(request, 'pizzahome/cart.html', {'title': 'корзина', 'cart': cart})

#models
class Cart(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=PROTECT)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Корзины')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Корзины')
        ordering = ('-creation_date',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)```
````

Answer (score 0):

а попробуйте filter()

```
cart = Cart.objects.filter(username=request.user)
```